# google maps - test that a point is valid

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I test that point is properly created if I cannot control that lat and lon are valid values?  Is there a method that can test that point is valid?

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lat` and `lon` must be numbers, valid ranges are:

- `latitude`(approximately): -85 to 85
- `longitude:`-180 to 180

So you may check the values e.g. via:

```
if(!isNaN(lat) && Math.abs(lat)<=85){/*valid latitude*/}
if(!isNaN(lon) && Math.abs(lon)<=180){/*valid longitude*/}
```